# Mappings to table ? payumbundle symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, mapping, payum

I am having a lot of difficulties with the payumbundle, however i think it's just because i don't understand on how to import mappings

They payum bundle in symfony2 comes with the mappings:

```
mappings:
    payum:
        is_bundle: false
        type: xml
        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping
        prefix: Payum\Bridge\Doctrine\Entity
    payum_paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
        is_bundle: false
        type: xml
        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping
        prefix: Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Bridge\Doctrine\Entity
```

Now i always get the error that a table does not exist like here:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'payum_dev.payum_paypal_express_checkout_payment_details' doesn't exist
```

But they never explain on how to create this table, as there is no SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved my problem, i just had to run the following command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Comment: Payum itself does not provide end model only mapped supper classes. So first you have to define mapping (as you did), second create your models which are extends basic ones (Dont forget to define id mapping). And at last run `schema:update`